# Search for an array of bytes in another process

Tags: delphi, memory

I wish to search for an array of bytes inside another process. I am using VirtualQueryEx and ReadProcessMemory but i am unsure of the correct what to do this.

Here is how my code looks so far:

```
procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
const
  Target: array[0..7] of byte = ($A0, $19, $40, $2B, $F6, $7F, $00, $00);
var
  Mbi: TMemoryBasicInformation;
  Handle: THandle;
  buff: array of byte;
  hWin, ProcID, BuffSize: Cardinal;
  Addr: DWORD_PTR;
  BytesRead: NativeUInt;
  i: integer;
begin
  hWin := FindWindow(nil, 'Minesweeper');
  if hWin > 0 then
    GetWindowThreadProcessID(hWin, @ProcId);
  if ProcId > 0 then
  begin
    Handle := OpenProcess(PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION or PROCESS_VM_READ, false, ProcId);
    if Handle <> 0 then
    begin
      while (VirtualQueryEx(Handle, Ptr(Addr), Mbi, SizeOf(Mbi)) <> 0) do
      begin
        SetLength(buff, BuffSize);
        if ReadProcessMemory(Handle, Mbi.BaseAddress, Buff, Mbi.RegionSize, BytesRead) then
        begin
          for i := 0 to Length(Buff) do
          if CompareMem(@Buff[i], @Target[1], Length(Target)) then
          begin
            ShowMessage('Found');
          end;
        end;
        if Addr + BuffSize < Addr then
          break;
        Addr := Addr + BuffSize;
      end;
      SetLength(buff, 0);
      CloseHandle(Handle);
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Program freezes.

Comment: Start by doing some debugging. Work out where the code hangs

Comment: You don't seem to be initialising BuffSize.

Comment: You are not initializing `Addr`, either. And `if Addr + BuffSize < Addr` does not make sense, unless you are expecting `Addr + BuffSize` to wrap around zero.

Comment: Usually, such code (`if A + B < A`) is used to detect a carry or overflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of issues with your code.
Rather than spoonfeed the solution I'm going to explain where to get the info.

**Every** local variable that you use, must be initialized beforehand.

**Initialize local variables**
The following vars are not initialized:

```
{mbi - Set to zero using} FillChar(mbi, SizeOf(Mbi), #0);

BuffSize:= 1024*4 + SizeOf(Target);
//Also add a 
const
  DefaultBufSize = 1024*4;
```

**Do *not* start reading from 0**
Instead initialize `Addr` to the starting address of the process using [`GetModuleInfo`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683201%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
Don't forget to initialize the `mi: TModuleInfo` structure using:
`FillChar(mi, SizeOf(mi), #0);`

**Read a 4k+ buffer**
Now keep loading buffers of `BuffSize`, but only increase `Addr` with `DefaultBuffSize`.

**Check how many bytes are actually read**
Make sure to check the `BytesRead` parameter and reduce the `BuffSize` if fewer bytes are read (or you'll get access violations).

**Utilize a smart search algorithm**
Use the following routine to find the string:

Boyer-Moore-Horspool string search algorithm - [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boyer%E2%80%93Moore%E2%80%93Horspool_algorithm)
[(Thanks to: Dorin Duminica)](https://web.archive.org/web/20101108170934/http://www.delphigeist.com/2010/04/boyer-moore-horspool-in-delphi-2010.html)

```
{$PointerMath on}
function FindMem(P1: pointer; Size1: Cardinal; P2: Pointer; Size2: Cardinal): Integer;
var
  i,j,k: Integer;
  LenPattern: Integer;
  LenValue: Integer;
  SkipTable: array[byte] of Integer;
  Found: Boolean;
  B: Byte;

    function __SameByte: Boolean;
    begin
      Result := (PByte(P1)[i] = PByte(P2)[j])
    end; // function __SameChar: Boolean;

begin
  Found := False;
  Result := -1;
  LenPattern := size2;
  if LenPattern = 0 then begin
    Result := 0;
    Found := True;
  end; // if LenPattern = 0
  for B:= low(byte) to high(byte) do SkipTable[B]:= LenPattern;
  for k:= 1 to LenPattern - 1 do SkipTable[PByte(P2)[k]]:= LenPattern - k;
  k:= LenPattern + 0;
  LenValue := size1;
  while (not Found) and (k <= LenValue) do begin
    i := k;
    j := LenPattern;
    while (j >= 1) do begin
      if __SameByte then begin
        j := j -1;
        i := i -1;
      end else
        j := -1;
      if j = 0 then begin
        Result := i;
        Found := True;
      end; // if j = 0 
      k := k + SkipTable[PByte(P1)[k]];
    end; // while (j >= 1)
  end; // while (not Found) and (k <= Size1)
end;
```

See [here for info on GetModuleInfo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683201%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Good luck